# Wine return code: 13568 - App not starting

Tags: wine, lutris

I am running in 64-bit mode, trying to launch adobe fireworks. Having previously fixed this error  `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.` with: https://github.com/FeralInteractive/gamemode/issues/254#issuecomment-643648779
The log:

```
Running gamemoderun /home/hutber/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-6.10-7-x86_64/bin/wine /mnt/users/Games/Games/fireworks/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Adobe Fireworks CS6/Fireworks.exe
Initial process has started with pid 382179
Start monitoring process.
gamemodeauto: 
wineserver: using server-side synchronization.
Monitored process exited.
Initial process has exited (return code: 13568)
All monitored processes have exited.
Exit with returncode 13568
```

I also have `lib32-libldap` installed as suggested in other posts:

```
sudo apt-get install libldap-2.4-2:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libldap-2.4-2:i386 is already the newest version (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8).
libldap-2.4-2:i386 set to manually installed.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 208 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same error, after applying the exact same fix. What a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13568 wants u to install the following VC++ libraries in order to compile scripts: *mfc42.dll*, *mfc42u.dll*. Use winetricks to download them and latest stable wine version when launching app with lutris.
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when trying to run Pathos (nethack) through lutris, and installing the `mfc42` dependency like @IvanPetrov suggested didnt helped. After having a closer look at the lutris stdout, i found that the installer was downloading a file from `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6A90ACBBC72A730C&resid=6A90ACBBC72A730C%2153593&authkey=ADWIzs7sC8oQw1g` and used the last part of the url as filename (so: `download?cid=6A90ACBBC72A730C&resid=6A90ACBBC72A730C%2153593&authkey=ADWIzs7sC8oQw1g`, which caused problems later on (i think because of the `?`) so the installer was raising an file-not-found error. Not sure though if `13568` means FnF in general or if this is something less generic. Anyways, i solved that by serving the installer myself from something like `http://localhost/PathosSetup.exe` and that fixed the problem.
Maybe someone finds this helpful :)